# Convert line feeds to an actual string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, string-matching, tr

I have a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date "+%F %R:%S") ":: yum update"
/usr/bin/yum update -y
```

I want to convert that to exactly this quoted string:

```
"#!/bin/bash\necho $(date \"+%F %R:%S\") \":: yum update\"\n/usr/bin/yum update -y\n"
```

Any method I have used is matching the line feeds but converts them to a line feed instead of to "\n". So these examples:

```
sed 's/\n/\n/g' file
sed 's/\n/\\\n/g' file
tr '\n' '\n' <file
tr '\n' "\n" <file
```

all result in exactly the same output as the file itself. So how do I match the line feed character and replace it with the actual string "\n" and not something that will itself be recognized as a line feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you want two characters, slash and `n`, to replace a single newline.  Consequently, `tr` is not a good choice.

It wasn't clear to me if you wanted actual backslashes to precede your double quotes or not.  The answers below assume that you do.  If you don't, it is simple enough the remove those substitutions.

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/"/, "\\\""); printf "%s\\n",$0}' file
#!/bin/bash\necho $(date \"+%F %R:%S\") \":: yum update\"\n/usr/bin/yum update -y\n
```

#### Using `sed`

```
$ sed ':again; N; $!b again; s/"/\\"/g; s/\n/\\n/g; s/$/\\n/' file
#!/bin/bash\necho $(date \"+%F %R:%S\") \":: yum update\"\n/usr/bin/yum update -y\n
```

Comment: I did want backslashes preceding double quotes, thank you. Both answers work

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\n/g; s/"/\\"/g' file
```

`tr` cannot do this job because it cannot translate one char (<kbd>\n</kbd>) into a 2-char string (<kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>).